# Form input submit to table with this data

Tags: php, jquery, html, octobercms

Helou, 
I have a form like this

```
<form id="some" data-request="checkout" class="checkoutForm">
 <div class="form-group mb10">
                                    <label for="firstName" class="col-sm-12">Name <span class="color-main">*</span></label>
                                    <input class="form-control checkout-form-border" id="firstName" value="" type="text">
</div>
 <div class="form-group mb10">
                                    <label for="Address" class="col-sm-12">Address <span class="color-main">*</span></label>
                                    <input class="form-control checkout-form-border" id="address" value="" type="text">
</div>
etc etc ....
</form>
```

Now, I want on submit button show new page with collected data from this form in a table body. 
Can I do this via php and jquery or new custom component? 
Thanx

Comment: simple answer yes

Comment: ^ I concur with that. Did you try something first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP:

need a submit button  in the form

need action=" " and method="post" attributes added to your form tag

need to add name attributes to your input boxes

Top of page,

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $variable = $_POST['namedOfInputBox'];
    echo "<table><tr><td>$variable</td></tr></table>";
{
```

What that says is if the form is submitted (submit being name of your submit button, generally name it submit), the values coming through are these and in PHP we "echo", or print, out html code and place our variable here. You can either use :

```
echo "<table><tr><td>$variable</td></tr></table>";
```

or

```
echo "<table><tr><td>" . $variable . "</td></tr></table>";
```

Comment: if you're going to post an answer, post one without syntax errors ;-) they don't seem to know much about php syntax.

Comment: thanx !! :-) and for each input box i need $_POST?

Comment: syntax Error: unknown end of file

Comment: Forms do not require an `action` or `method` as these both have defaults if you care to use them. A form without an action submits to the same page and the default method is GET.

Comment: But you "should" have them in html5...because I showed how to use with POST and not GET.      @GoranNovacic  Any form input coming through is stored in the POST variable array. You access them by using $_POST['nameofformitem'].  So each input box needs a name="thisisaname" in your form so you can access that specific inputted value when the form is submitted.   In your PHP code you access that with $_POST['thisisaname"].   So if you type 5 into the box and hit submit, it'll come through as 5.             I also went back and fixed the syntax errors.

Comment: Thanx clearshot66, same as I supposed.